# Undocumented GraphComputation`GraphProduct usage

Tags: graphs-and-networks, undocumented, mathworld

According to [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCartesianProduct.html) there is an undocumented function

```
GraphComputation`GraphProduct[G1, G2, "Cartesian"]
```

To compute the cartesian graph product.

Now in line with the example shown:

[image]

I would expect

```
GraphComputation`GraphProduct[PathGraph[Range[2]], PathGraph[Range[3]], "Cartesian"]
```

To product the ladder graph shown on the right. Yet, the end result seems to be [image] which doesn't even have the right number of nodes.

Is the function just unfinished (and presumably the reason for its undocumented nature), or is there some way to coax it into providing the correct answer?

Comment: It does have 6 nodes but two nodes overlap as you can see by adding the options `VertexLabels -> "Name"` and `ImagePadding -> 20`.

Comment: ... You can set the layout using `GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {2, 3}}` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the given inputs `GraphProduct` produces a graph with 6 vertices, but, somehow,  vertices 1 and 6 overlap:

```
GraphComputation`GraphProduct[PathGraph[Range[2]], PathGraph[Range[3]], "Cartesian", 
 ImagePadding -> 20, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
VertexList @ %
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

You can use the option `GraphLayout` to specify the layout you would like to have, e.g.,

```
GraphComputation`GraphProduct[PathGraph[Range[2]], PathGraph[Range[3]], "Cartesian",
 ImagePadding -> 20, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {2, 3}}]
```

[image]